# Consulta Pivot Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas e quero retornar 1 consulta fazendo a soma do que foi vendido.

Tabela 1 = products
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela 2 = order
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela pivot = order_product
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como irei fazer para trazer uma listagem com o SKU, nome e quantidade vendida?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira utilizando o inner join:

```
SELECT P.SKU, P.NAME, SUM(OP.UNIT_VALUE) FROM ORDER_PRODUCT OP
INNER JOIN ORDER O ON O.ID = OP.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.ID = OP.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY P.SKU, P.NAME
```

Obs: Não utilizei nenhum campo da tabela Order, mas acho que da para você entender como deve fazer.